# Join scope in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to write a Rails 3 scope, on Client, to do the following:

```
select * from clients c, dependents d
where d.last_name like '%ss%' and c.id = d.client_id;
```

Dependent model:

```
class Dependent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  scope :by_last_name, (lambda do |name| { :conditions => ['last_name LIKE ?', "#{name}%"]} end )
```

Client model:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dependents, :dependent => :destroy
```

I have not yet been able to get a scope join to work syntactically. The dependent's last name needs to be passed in as a parameter.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_last_name, lambda { |last_name| includes(:dependents).where("dependents.last_name LIKE ?", "#{last_name}%") }
```

then call

```
Client.by_last_name "last_name"
```

Edit: Changed the code to reflect your problem.
Also find_by_id(1) is the same as find(1) except that it does not throw an error when nothing is found, instead it returns nil.

Comment: Novae, thanks. I need this to be a scope on Client. I'm also curious what the find_by_id(1) does.

Comment: Thanks much, Novae. Very nice. Worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
scope :by_last_name, lambda {|name| where("dependents.last_name like ?", "'%#{name}%'")
```

Comment: Erez, I had forgotten one detail - I need to pass the dependent's last name as a parameter. How could I add that to your answer?

Comment: Erez, thanks again. The problem I had with this is that Rails complains Unknown column 'dependents.last_name' in 'where clause':

Comment: Erez, thanks for your work on this. Novae's answer worked, but I learned from your work.